# undefined byte_size for hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to get around a get request in ruby.

```
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["DATA_URL"])
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    headers["Authorization"] = data["authHeader"]
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri,headers)
    response = http.request( request, form_data )
    JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Im not sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be because of form_data attribute. I use `URI.encode_www_form` when passing the data. You can refer here for URI::encode_www_form

You could do URI.encode_www_form( form_data ) and fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your form_data is probably a Hash and it needs to be formatted into a string. Try:

```
formatted_data = URI.encode_www_form(form_data)
response = http.request( request, formatted_data )
```

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form